# How to call a custom php file on magento product page

Tags: magento

if getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?> maps directly to catalog/product/view/type/simple.phtml by default, how do I map to my own file? If I wanted to create a file that would produce a small image to place on the product page, right under "availability" how would I tell magento to map to where I have put the file? From what I understand getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?> defaults to the file path: catalog/product/view/type/simple.phtml so how can I customize the magento defaults and tell it to map to my custom files i've created?

Could I do something like getChildHtml('etc/etc/my-file.phtml') ?>

Essentially, what I am trying to do is add a small image under "availability" of my site (ex: http://climbhigh.com/climbing/climbing-ropes/petzl-dragonfly-rope-8-2mm.html) that says free shipping. Just trying to find the best way to do it.

I hope I have explained this well enough, if not, please let me know and I will try to explain more. Any help or guidance would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out what I needed to do. I simply wanted to add a small image to my product detail page that highlight a free shipping option. All I had to do was create a static block in the admin panel of magento and go into catalog>product>view.phtml file and insert:

getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_block_id')->toHtml(); ?>

it worked like a charm!

thanks for the help Crags

Comment: you can create custom variable also to show image of free shipping all u want to call that custom variable

Answer (score 1):

The code `getChildHtml('product_type_data')` doesn't always map directly to the template file `catalog/product/view/type/simple.phtml`. It only maps to that file if the layout handle `PRODUCT_TYPE_simple` is loaded, i.e. if the current product is a simple product. In order to change the template to be a different one you need to update the template attribute in the layout. At it's most simple this can be achieved by editing `app/design/frontend/base/layout/catalog.xml` and changing the template attribute.

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="your/new/path.phtml">
```

Of course editing core files is a bad idea, so you should make a quick search for how to correctly add layout updates via either local.xml or customer layout update files.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your solution but had no luck. What I did was added: <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('free_shipping') ?> to view.phtml, added: <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
        <reference name="free.shipping">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/free-shipping.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_simple> to catalog.xml, and created the file: free-shipping.phtml. No luck so far...

Comment: If you change only the template attribute, you shouldn't be changing the view.phtml file. This should remain as `getChildHtml("product_type_data")`, the value passed to `getChildHtml` corresponds to the `as` attribute in the .xml file.